# pass parameters to javafx web start application

Tags: parameters, javafx, java-web-start

I a JavaFX application that uses Java Web Start to launch it. I'm trying to pass a parameter to it, but thus far I have been unsuccessful. I have try to follow the example given in the Deployment Toolkit. So here is where I'm at with everything right now.

**HMTL:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Parameter Testing</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Parameter Passing Test</h1>
        <script src="http://java.com/js/dtjava.js"></script>
        <script>
            function launchApplication() {
                dtjava.launch({url: 'ParamTesting.jnlp', params:{order: "852237"}}, {jvm: '1.7.0_72+', javafx: '2.2+'}, {});
                return false;
            }
        </script>
        <a href='ParamTesting.jnlp' onclick="return launchApplication();">
            <img src="images/jws-launch-button.png" width="88" height="23"/>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JNLP:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="ParamTesting.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Param Testing</title>
        <vendor>USGS</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <update check="always" policy="always" />
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.7.0_72+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="ParamTesting.jar" main="true" version="0.1"/>
        <property name="jnlp.versionEnabled" value="true"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc name="ParamTesting"/>
    <jfx:javafx-desc main-class="gov.usgs.tnm.paramtesting.MainApp" name="MainApp">
        <fx:param name="order" value="852237"/>
    </jfx:javafx-desc>
</jnlp>
```

**JavaFX start Method:**

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(getParameters().getNamed().get("order"));

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Scene.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/Styles.css");

    stage.setTitle("Parameter Testing");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Everytime I run this, "null" gets printed in the console. I cannot figure out where I'm going wrong.

Also, this application does have an order system associated with it so the parameter will need to be dynamic. If anyone has any insight into how I can accomplish this as well, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem. I don't need the application-describe element in the JNLP. I don't know why having it in there causes the parameters not to be accessible to the JavaFX program, but it does.